# VBA - get the actual cell's NumberFormat after applying conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Example:
We have simple cell with General formatting.

[image: fig 1]

Let's add conditional formatting that will change cell's NumberFormat to `"# ##0.00"`. Now it looks like this

[image: fig 2]

The question is how do I get the current NumberFormat for the cell from VBA code? Given that I need the format that is actually displayed.

When I try `.NumberFormat` or `.DisplayFormat.NumberFormat` - same result = "General".
Is there a way to get the correct Numberformat - `"# ##0.00"`?

[image: fig 3]

PS The reason why I need it - I'm trying to make a VBA macro that would save cells current formatting but remove all conditional formatting calculations.

Comment: Can reproduce (Excel Office 365, Win10)

Comment: @ Tim Williams: Do you mean that in your installation `DisplayFormat.NumberFormat` returns correctly?

Comment: @FaneDuru - no I mean I can reproduce the OP's observation: I get "General"

Comment: Seems like you will have to loop through the format conditions applied to that cell; figure out which one was triggered; and, based on that, you could return `theCell.FormatConditions(Index).NumberFormat`  *and @FaneDuru this does work in O365*

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld: But this will not be enough... Nobody knows that the current `NumberFormat` is a condition formatted one. So, it will also be  necessary to make a function able to extract the condition type, based on which the format is applied and check if this one or the cell `NumberFormat` should be used, I think.

Comment: @FaneDuru That is what I meant to imply when I wrote "which one was triggered"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Ron Rosefeld and @FaneDuru pointed out - guess the only solution is to loop through all the format conditions and get the one that worked. As expected it's quite tricky.

Fortunately I've found a function to determine which CF is currently active for the given cell (if any) - function ActiveCondition from http://www.cpearson.com/excel/cfcolors.htm. I've modified it and made CFNumberFormat function which does what I wanted. The code is below.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJyrD.png

One more valid notion - turned out `Rng.FormatConditions(n).NumberFormat` always returns Local number format (.NumberFormatLocal). Meaning if you need to apply this NumberFormat to some other cell you'll need to assign it to local number format:

```
Selection.NumberFormatLocal = Rng.FormatConditions(n).NumberFormat
```

If you don't then you might get unexpected escaped spaces in number format that will result in errors.

Function code:

```
    Private Function GetStrippedValue(CF As String) As String
        Dim Temp As String
        If InStr(1, CF, "=", vbTextCompare) Then
           Temp = Mid(CF, 2, Len(CF) - 1)
           If Left(Temp, 1) = "=" Then
               Temp = Mid(Temp, 2)
           End If
        Else
           Temp = CF
        End If
        GetStrippedValue = Temp
    End Function
    
    Private Function ActiveCondition(Rng As Range) As Integer
        Dim Ndx As Long
        Dim FC As FormatCondition
        Dim Temp As Variant
        Dim Temp2 As Variant
        
        If Rng.FormatConditions.Count = 0 Then
            ActiveCondition = 0
        Else
            For Ndx = 1 To Rng.FormatConditions.Count
                Set FC = Rng.FormatConditions(Ndx)
                Select Case FC.Type
                    Case xlCellValue
                    Select Case FC.Operator
                        Case xlBetween
                            Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                            Temp2 = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula2)
                            If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                               If CDbl(Rng.Value) >= CDbl(Temp) And _
                                   CDbl(Rng.Value) <= CDbl(Temp2) Then
                                   ActiveCondition = Ndx
                                   Exit Function
                               End If
                           Else
                              If Rng.Value >= Temp And _
                                 Rng.Value <= Temp2 Then
                                 ActiveCondition = Ndx
                                 Exit Function
                              End If
                           End If
        
                        Case xlGreater
                            Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                            If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                               If CDbl(Rng.Value) > CDbl(Temp) Then
                                  ActiveCondition = Ndx
                                  Exit Function
                               End If
                            Else
                               If Rng.Value > Temp Then
                                  ActiveCondition = Ndx
                                  Exit Function
                               End If
                            End If
        
                        Case xlEqual
                            Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                            If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                               If CDbl(Rng.Value) = CDbl(Temp) Then
                                   ActiveCondition = Ndx
                                   Exit Function
                               End If
                            Else
                               If Temp = Rng.Value Then
                                  ActiveCondition = Ndx
                                  Exit Function
                               End If
                            End If
        
        
                        Case xlGreaterEqual
                            Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                            If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                               If CDbl(Rng.Value) >= CDbl(Temp) Then
                                   ActiveCondition = Ndx
                                   Exit Function
                               End If
                            Else
                               If Rng.Value >= Temp Then
                                  ActiveCondition = Ndx
                                  Exit Function
                               End If
                            End If
        
                      
                        Case xlLess
                            Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                            If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                                If CDbl(Rng.Value) < CDbl(Temp) Then
                                   ActiveCondition = Ndx
                                   Exit Function
                                End If
                            Else
                                If Rng.Value < Temp Then
                                   ActiveCondition = Ndx
                                   Exit Function
                                End If
                            End If
        
                        Case xlLessEqual
                            Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                            If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                               If CDbl(Rng.Value) <= CDbl(Temp) Then
                                  ActiveCondition = Ndx
                                  Exit Function
                               End If
                            Else
                               If Rng.Value <= Temp Then
                                  ActiveCondition = Ndx
                                  Exit Function
                               End If
                            End If
        
        
                        Case xlNotEqual
                            Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                            If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                               If CDbl(Rng.Value) <> CDbl(Temp) Then
                                  ActiveCondition = Ndx
                                  Exit Function
                               End If
                            Else
                               If Temp <> Rng.Value Then
                                  ActiveCondition = Ndx
                                  Exit Function
                               End If
                            End If
        
                       Case xlNotBetween
                            Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                            Temp2 = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula2)
                            If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                               If Not (CDbl(Rng.Value) <= CDbl(Temp)) And _
                                  (CDbl(Rng.Value) >= CDbl(Temp2)) Then
                                  ActiveCondition = Ndx
                                  Exit Function
                               End If
                            Else
                               If Not Rng.Value <= Temp And _
                                  Rng.Value >= Temp2 Then
                                  ActiveCondition = Ndx
                                  Exit Function
                               End If
                            End If
                    
                       Case Else
                            Debug.Print "UNKNOWN OPERATOR"
                   End Select
        
        
                Case xlExpression
                    If Application.Evaluate(FC.Formula1) Then
                       ActiveCondition = Ndx
                       Exit Function
                    End If
        
                Case Else
                    Debug.Print "UNKNOWN TYPE"
               End Select
        
            Next Ndx
        
        End If
        
        ActiveCondition = 0
    
    End Function
    
    Private Function CFNumberFormat(Rng As Range) As String
    
        Dim AC As Integer
        AC = ActiveCondition(Rng)
        If AC = 0 Then
            CFNumberFormat = Rng.NumberFormatLocal
        Else
            CFNumberFormat = Rng.FormatConditions(AC).NumberFormat
        End If
    
    End Function


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJyrD.png
```

Answer (score 0):

This code was almost exactly what I needed except for a few issues. It can be that you more than one active conditional format on a single cell. This raises several issues:

1. Which conditional format has priority? Excel applies the conditional formats in numerical order. If multiple conditional formats are active, then the numerically earliest one that affects the number format (or any other type of format) will be used.
2. Some conditional formats do not set the number format. A conditional format that does not set the number format sets it to "".
3. There is a "Stop if True" tick box in the conditional formatting dialog box that tells Excel to ignore all further conditional formatting rules.

Thus, I rewrote the code (and added a check for the xlNoBlanksCondition condition)

```
Private Function GetStrippedValue(CF As String) As String
Dim Temp As String
    If InStr(1, CF, "=", vbTextCompare) Then
        Temp = Mid(CF, 2, Len(CF) - 1)
        If Left(Temp, 1) = "=" Then
            Temp = Mid(Temp, 2)
        End If
    Else
        Temp = CF
    End If
    GetStrippedValue = Temp
End Function
    
Private Function ConditionIsActive(rng As Range, idx As Long) As Boolean
Dim FC As FormatCondition
Dim Temp As Variant
Dim Temp2 As Variant

    If idx < 1 Or idx > rng.FormatConditions.count Then
        ConditionIsActive = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Set FC = rng.FormatConditions(idx)
    Select Case FC.Type
        Case xlCellValue
        Select Case FC.Operator
            Case xlBetween
                Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                Temp2 = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula2)
                If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                   If CDbl(rng.Value) >= CDbl(Temp) And _
                       CDbl(rng.Value) <= CDbl(Temp2) Then
                       ConditionIsActive = True
                       Exit Function
                   End If
               Else
                  If rng.Value >= Temp And _
                     rng.Value <= Temp2 Then
                     ConditionIsActive = True
                     Exit Function
                  End If
               End If
    
            Case xlGreater
                Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                   If CDbl(rng.Value) > CDbl(Temp) Then
                      ConditionIsActive = True
                      Exit Function
                   End If
                Else
                   If rng.Value > Temp Then
                      ConditionIsActive = True
                      Exit Function
                   End If
                End If
    
            Case xlEqual
                Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                   If CDbl(rng.Value) = CDbl(Temp) Then
                       ConditionIsActive = True
                       Exit Function
                   End If
                Else
                   If Temp = rng.Value Then
                      ConditionIsActive = True
                      Exit Function
                   End If
                End If
    
    
            Case xlGreaterEqual
                Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                   If CDbl(rng.Value) >= CDbl(Temp) Then
                       ConditionIsActive = True
                       Exit Function
                   End If
                Else
                   If rng.Value >= Temp Then
                      ConditionIsActive = True
                      Exit Function
                   End If
                End If
    
          
            Case xlLess
                Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                    If CDbl(rng.Value) < CDbl(Temp) Then
                       ConditionIsActive = True
                       Exit Function
                    End If
                Else
                    If rng.Value < Temp Then
                       ConditionIsActive = True
                       Exit Function
                    End If
                End If
    
            Case xlLessEqual
                Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                   If CDbl(rng.Value) <= CDbl(Temp) Then
                      ConditionIsActive = True
                      Exit Function
                   End If
                Else
                   If rng.Value <= Temp Then
                      ConditionIsActive = True
                      Exit Function
                   End If
                End If
    
    
            Case xlNotEqual
                Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                   If CDbl(rng.Value) <> CDbl(Temp) Then
                      ConditionIsActive = True
                      Exit Function
                   End If
                Else
                   If Temp <> rng.Value Then
                      ConditionIsActive = True
                      Exit Function
                   End If
                End If
    
           Case xlNotBetween
                Temp = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula1)
                Temp2 = GetStrippedValue(FC.Formula2)
                If IsNumeric(Temp) Then
                   If Not (CDbl(rng.Value) <= CDbl(Temp)) And _
                      (CDbl(rng.Value) >= CDbl(Temp2)) Then
                      ConditionIsActive = True
                      Exit Function
                   End If
                Else
                   If Not rng.Value <= Temp And _
                      rng.Value >= Temp2 Then
                      ConditionIsActive = True
                      Exit Function
                   End If
                End If
                                    
           Case Else
                Debug.Print "UNKNOWN OPERATOR"
                ConditionIsActive = False
       End Select
    
    Case xlNoBlanksCondition
        If Not IsEmpty(rng) Then
            ConditionIsActive = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    
    
    Case xlExpression
        If Application.Evaluate(FC.Formula1) Then
           ConditionIsActive = True
           Exit Function
        End If
    
    Case Else
        Debug.Print "UNKNOWN TYPE"
        ConditionIsActive = False
    End Select
    
    ConditionIsActive = False
End Function
        
Function CFNumberFormat(rng As Range) As String
Dim idx As Long
Dim FC As FormatCondition
    CFNumberFormat = "General"
    For idx = 1 To rng.FormatConditions.count
        Set FC = rng.FormatConditions(idx)
        If ConditionIsActive(rng, idx) Then
            If FC.numberFormat <> "" Then
                CFNumberFormat = FC.numberFormat
                Exit Function
            End If
            If FC.StopIfTrue Then
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next idx
End Function
```